# Why is my Post FromBody null in my API call?

Tags: json, api, .net-core

I am getting null for no reason in my API. Why is this?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("category")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostProductCategory([FromBody] ProductCategoryViewModel message)
```

model:

```
    public class ProductCategoryViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Advantages { get; set; }
        public decimal? Liambda { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string UseCase { get; set; }
        public string UseCaseTwo { get; set; }
        public int? PackageType { get; set; }
    }
```

json that i send :

```
{
advantages: "",
description: "",
icon: "",
id: 0,
liambda: "1111",
name: "asdfas",
packageType: 1,
useCase: "",
useCaseTwo: ""
}
```

Comment: That's not valid json

Comment: how is this not valid?

Comment: JSON property names **must** be quoted.

Comment: ok fixed the problem. It was quoted, I just copied from other place. the problem was when I enter data in JS I used input field "text" for decimal? value. and that is why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed the problem. It was quoted, I just copied from other place. the problem was when I enter data in JS I used input field "text" for decimal? value. and that is why it was not working.